# PHP Fatal Error: Out of memory

Tags: memory

My website is facing a PHP Fatal Error: Out of memory.

I had tried the following method, such as

- Increase **`memory_limit`** to 1GB via .user.ini
  [image]
- Add **`RLimitMEM`** max into .htaccess
- Optimize database

Due to the error_log quite long. I uploaded it to Google Drive.
[PHP error_log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2V8gTEWnbCbbnMyOFJCaGw1Zzg)

But the problem is occurring.

Anyone also facing this issue but managed to solve them?

Thanks.

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to the default theme. Does it still happen?

Comment: Currently I cannot disable all the plugins because the website is currently live. If I switch off all the plugin, I afraid the website will deface.

Comment: A fatal error isn't "live". :)

Comment: After I check with the host, they said it is because of other websites consume too much memory and lead to the website got this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is four possible ways to solve this.

1. **Try adding this line to your wp-config.php file:**

   define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M');
2. **If you have access to your PHP.ini file, change the line in PHP.ini**

   memory_limit = 1024M ;
3. **Using htacess.**

   php_value memory_limit 1024M
4. **if still not solve then**

   Talk to your host.